# Fix positioned element stops at certain point when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

box2 is a fix positioned element, I need it stops at the top and bottom of box1 when scrolling. Any help would be appreciated.

```
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     var h1 = $('.box1').height();
     var h2 = $('.box2').height();
     var h3 = $('.footer').outerHeight(true);
    $('.box2').css('bottom', h3);
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/7537247/y5psn0f7/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want `box2` to appear static within the viewport, except it should never go above or below `box1`'s extent.

Use this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop= $(window).scrollTop(),
      b1= $('.box1'),
      b2= $('.box2'),
      min= b1.position().top,
      max= (b1.position().top + b1.outerHeight()) - b2.outerHeight();

  b2.css({
    top: Math.min(Math.max(scrollTop,min),max) - scrollTop
  });
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/edjd4gxf/)

Comment: This is a very elegant answer. +1

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rick, this piece of code works great in all browsers, but IE. It seems like when scrolls in absolute position in IE, it flickers. However, when using fixed position, this issue won't happen, any idea what's going on with this, and what's the best approach to fix this.

Comment: Ah, it's always IE, isn't it?  I've restored the fixed positioning and updated the answer.  This should get rid of most (but not all) of the IE flickering problems.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Rick, fixed position seems working better than absolute position, but it still has flickers when scrolling to top and bottom in IEs, which is so annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer from [Rick Hitchcock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3903374/rick-hitchcock), made some improvements:

```
var $b1 = $('.box1'); // 1
var $b2 = $('.box2'); // 1
var min = $b2.position().top; // 2

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var max = ($b1.position().top + $b1.outerHeight()) - $b2.outerHeight();

  $b2.css({
    top: Math.min(Math.max(scrollTop, min), max)
  });
});
```

1. Cache DOM queries
2. Make `min` the original top of `$b2` on page load.

[jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/xopage/1/edit?css,js,output)